# Delete textboxes but keep comments

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which fires via `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. However, it appears comments are getting deleted as well. How can I keep comments?

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("B5:B34")) Is Nothing Or Target = "" Then
    For Each bx In ActiveSheet.TextBoxes
        bx.Delete
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something along those lines:

```
Sub DeleteTextboxesButKeepComments
    Dim bx As Excel.TextBox
    Dim oComment As Excel.Comment
    Dim dicCommentNames As Object 'Scripting.Dictionary

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    'Build a dictionary of the worksheet's comment's shape names.
    Set dicCommentNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dicCommentNames.CompareMode = VbCompareMethod.vbBinaryCompare
    For Each oComment In Target.Worksheet.Comments
        dicCommentNames(oComment.Shape.Name) = True
    Next oComment

    If Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B5:B34")) Is Nothing Then 'Or Target = "" Then
        For Each bx In Target.Worksheet.TextBoxes
            'Avoid deleting textboxes whose name is among those used for comments.
            If Not dicCommentNames.Exists(bx.Name) Then
                bx.Delete
            End If
        Next
    End If

Cleanup:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Resume Cleanup
End Sub
```

I'm not sure what you want to do by testing for `Target = ""` but it won't work if there are more than 1 cell in Target. Let me know and I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Getting a `resume without error` message box followed by a blank message box which repeats infinitely. `dicCommentNames(oComment.Shape.Name)` should be an iteration for the parameter instead of `.name` then `=.name`?

Comment: My very bad; add Exit Sub after `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. I'll update the answer.